# Como parar o serviço do Windows ao executar o instalador e iniciar logo após a instalação via Inno Setup

Tags: delphi, windows, instalador, inno-setup, setup

Estou usando o **Inno Setup** para criar um instalador, nesse instalador contém uma aplicação e um **serviço do windows**, já configurei no **Inno Setup** para substituir os arquivos já existentes ao instalar novamente.

Mas minha dúvida é, como parar o serviço ao executar o instalador e iniciar ele novamente ao terminar de instalar. Essas operações quero que faça silenciosamente, ou seja, ocultar a execução.

OBS: Se o serviço existe ou não, não preciso verificar.

Alguém sabe se isso é possível de se fazer no **Inno Setup**.

Comment: Esse cara sugere alguns eventos do Inno http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390996/inno-setup-properly-stop-service-before-file-copy.
Eu usaria um próprio comando windows: start/stop install/unisntall

Comment: @VictorTadashi vou dar uma olhada, valeu por ajudar!

Answer (score -2):

Caso alguém ainda precise dessa solução, tente o seguinte:

```
function StopService(serviceName: string): boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  Exec('net.exe', 'stop "' + serviceName + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  Result := (ResultCode = 0);
end;

function StartService(serviceName: string): boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  Exec('net.exe', 'start "' + serviceName + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  Result := (ResultCode = 0);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    StopService('NomeDoSeuServico');
  end
  else if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    StartService('NomeDoSeuServico');
  end;
end;
```